# How can I add "recent documents" to the bookmarks sidebar?

Tags: unity, nautilus

I really like the "recent documents" bookmark that appears when I'm adding a file with a dialog opened by a program. How can I do so that it always appears among the bookmards in the sidebar when I open a new nautilus folder view?